# Does the total amount of lookups affect performance in a CAML query that has less than 8 lookup columns?

Tags: lookup-column, caml

I have a large library with 12 lookup columns, and while I only use 6 of these columns when I retrieve data from this library (in a CAML query), the retrieval process often takes 20-30 seconds. Would deleting lookup columns that are not included in the CAML query improve performance, or would it be pointless?